# Unable to "explode" spark vector from PCA

Tags: scala, apache-spark, vector, pca

I am trying to scatter plot the 2 features resulting from the PCA in spark ml library.
To be more precise I am trying to convert result into something like this:

```
_________
id | X | Y
__________
1  |0.1|0.1
2  |0.2|0.2
3  |0.4|0.4
4  |0.3|0.3
...

from something like this

_________
id | pca
__________
1  |[0.1,0.1]
2  |[0.2,0.2]
3  |[0.4,0.4]
4  |[0.3,0.3]
...
```

But it seem that spark vector aren't iterable or something like this. I don't understand what is going on. If someone know the answer that would be grate

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler


val convertToVector = udf((array: Array[Double]) => {
  Vectors.dense(array.toArray)
})

val convertToDouble = udf((array: Array[Float]) => {
  array.map(_.toDouble).toArray
})

val ds = model.userFactors.withColumn("features", convertToDouble($"features"))
val userMatrixDs = ds.withColumn("features", convertToVector($"features"))

//val df3 = assembler.transform(df2)

val pca = new PCA()
    .setInputCol("features")
    .setOutputCol("pca")
    .setK(2)
    .fit(userMatrixDs)
// Project vectors to the linear space spanned by the top 2 principal
// components, keeping the label
val result = pca.transform(userMatrixDs).select("id","pca");

result.show()

result.select(
    result.id,
    result.col("pca")[0].as("eigenVector1"),
    result.col("pca")[1].as("eigenVector2")
  )
  .show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this example:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row(1, 1.0, 2.0))),
StructType(
  List(
    StructField("id", IntegerType),
    StructField("one", DoubleType),
    StructField("two", DoubleType)
  )
))

import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
import spark.implicits._

val assembler =
  new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("one", "two"))
    .setOutputCol("vector")

val df0 = assembler.transform(df)

df0
  .select("id", "vector")
  .as[(Int, Vector)]
  .map { case (id, vector) =>
    val arr = vector.toArray
    (id, arr(0), arr(1))
  }
  .select($"_1".as("id"), $"_2".as("pca_x"), $"_3".as("pca_y"))
```

First I create with VectorAsembler a Vector column and then extract the value transforming it to a Dataset[(Int, Vector)]. With map you can easily manipulate the row.